# Filtering Foreign Key Based on Another SlugRelatedField in POST Requests in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and have a model with multiple `ForeignKey` relationships and am `POST`ing their slugs rather than `id`.  The issue is that the second `ForeignKey` requires a queryset that is filtered based on the first.  Here is a not-so-perfect example:

```
# models.py
class Student(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(...)

class Class_(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(...)

class ReportCard(models.Model)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    class_ = models.ForeignKey(Class_)
    grade = models.CharField(...)
```

```
# serializers.py
class ReportCardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=models.Student.objects.all(), slug_field='slug')
    class_ = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=models.Class_.objects.filter(???), slug_field='slug')  # need to filter based on student here

    class Meta:
        model = models.ReportCard
        fields = '__all__'  # use all fields
```

How do I do this?  `student` in the serializer does not return the model and I don't know how to access the data inside of `ReportCardSerializer` to grab the string from the `POST` request to manually filter `class_`.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you don't need to validate in a get request, it's enough validating in a post request so override validate method:

```
class ReportCardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=models.Student.objects.all(), slug_field='slug')
    class_ = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=models.Class_.objects.all(), slug_field='slug')

    class Meta:
        model = models.ReportCard
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        student = data.get('student')
        class_ = data.get('class_')

        if check class_ is valid for the student, if not raise error:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("class_ is invalid")
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Unfortunately, the problem here is that the `class_` slug is not unique unless filtered by the `student`, so you end up with `MultipleObjectsReturned` and the serializer errors out before being validated.

Comment: Then use charfield instead of slugrelatedfield